# Create a queue in Nextcord for discord bot using python

Tags: python, discord, queue, playback, nextcord

I'm trying to make a music discord bot using nextcord, I managed to make a play command but when I play a song and put another song it just changes, I want to queue to solve this problem but I don't know where to start, can anyone help?

this is my play command:

```
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx: commands.Context, *, search: wavelink.YouTubeTrack):
    if not ctx.voice_client:
        vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
        

    await vc.play(search)
    await ctx.send(f"Now playing: `{search.title}`")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you already tried in order to make a queue work?

Comment: This question may helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66630409/python-discord-music-bot-creating-a-queue-automatically-playing-the-next-son